# Featured Images for Tags?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, customization, images, tags

Is it possible to somehow create featured images for tags or custom taxonomies.

For the sake of explanation, I will give an example of the possible functionality.

Say I am running a website that posts the best restaurants by city. Some of my tags could be London, Paris NYC, etc... I have a page that grabs these tags and sorts them alphabetically. But rather than just have text, it would have the tag name (London for example) and an image for that city.

I know this could be done manually, but by attaching an image to the tag or custom taxonomy, it could make the process a bit easier, especially if dealing with a great number of tags/custom taxonomies.

I reckon this might be a bit more of an abstract question, but I am curious if anyone has come across any blogs or websites that are doing this successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this plugin for exactly the same purpose (and for other taxonomies we got that need a featured image): http://wordpress.org/plugins/gecka-terms-thumbnails/

Comment: very cool, I am going to investigate this plugin. Is there any websites you know of that successfully using the plugin to do what I describe above? The plugin page and homepage showed admins screens but no real life examples of it working. Thanks!

Comment: Jacob: here's a couple of examples where I use this plugin:

Comment: 1) I have a custom taxonomy called "writers" (because we are a news site, and so writer's credit has nothing to do with the built-in wordpress "author". For us, "author" is the editor, and there's a custom tax that behaves like tags, which is where the writer's credit us used). So for writers, we wanted a photo of course. 

So this is what a writer's page looks like for example: http://www.timesofisrael.com/writers/david-horovitz/

Comment: 2) Something closer to what you're going to do - we have a custom taxonomy called "cities", and for each city there's an image. Here's an example of how we utilize it (see bottom part of the page, under the map): http://www.timesofisrael.com/the-jewish-planet/

3) On a different site, we use it in the most straight forward way possible: some tags have a photo (and a description) because they're "important". So here's an example of such a tag page: http://www.the7eye.org.il/topic/%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%97%D7%99-%D7%93%D7%A0%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%A8/

Comment: Thanks Birat, this is actually what I am trying to get. Thank you so much for the help! Great examples as well!